# Use VBA to run Access Query for email addresses to use as email recipients for generated email

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm running a query EmailList that pulls the email addresses of the people displayed on an Access Form. The query runs ok by itself, populating the field Email with the intended recipients. I'd like to use VBA to copy the emails displayed in this query to a new email with them listed as recipients. I need the email to be html since I'm attaching a hyperlink in the body of the email.

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
OutApp.Session.Logon
Set OutMail = OutApp.createitem(0)

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim qry As DAO.QueryDefs
Dim CurrentDb As DAO.Database
Dim OlApp As Object
Dim OlMail As Object
Dim ToRecipient As String

  Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set OlMail = OlApp.createitem(olmailitem)
  Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Email FROM [EmailList]")

  Do While rs.EOF = False
    ToRecipient = rs!Email
    OlMail.Recipients.Add ToRecipient
    rs.MoveNext
  Loop

With OutMail
    .Subject = "MOC"
    .HTMLbody = "<a href=""X:\MOC Training.accdb"">Click Here for Training</a><br>"
    .Display
End With
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

When playing around with this, I only get blanks as my recipient or it is erroring on my "Set rs" line item. I'm fairly new to VBA, so I don't understand the error.

See the SQL code below:

```
SELECT Employees.Email
FROM Employees LEFT JOIN Names2 ON Employees.Employee = Names2.[Names Trainee]
WHERE (((Names2.MOC)=[Forms]![Input MOC]![cboMOC#]));
```

Comment: Edit question to post the query SQL statement. Assume the form is open when code runs? This code is behind that form? Why do you have those SET lines at the beginning? Do you have `Option Explicit` in the module header? You are declaring multiple variables for same type of objects then using variables inconsistently. Don't use `CurrentDb` as a declared variable - it is already an intrinsic constant.

Comment: I've attached the SQL code used for the query.                                    SELECT Employees.Email
FROM Employees LEFT JOIN Names2 ON Employees.Employee = Names2.[Names Trainee]
WHERE (((Names2.MOC)=[Forms]![Input MOC]![cboMOC#]));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate problem is with `OpenRecordset`, not really anything to do with Outlook.  So let's ignore the Outlook bits for now and focus on the `OpenRecordset` problem.

The error happens because `OpenRecordset` can not retrieve the value from your combo box:

```sql
WHERE (((Names2.MOC)=[Forms]![Input MOC]![cboMOC#]))
```

Instead it regards `[Forms]![Input MOC]![cboMOC#]` as a parameter for which you have not supplied a value.  So supply that value before calling `OpenRecordset`.

Paste this code into a new procedure and run it.  You can view the `Debug.Print` output in the Immediate window; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> will take you there.

```vba
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strSelect As String
strSelect = "SELECT e.Email FROM Employees As e " & _
    "INNER JOIN Names2 As n ON e.Employee = n.[Names Trainee] " & _
    "WHERE n.MOC=[Forms]![Input MOC]![cboMOC#];"
Debug.Print "strSelect: " & strSelect
Debug.Print "combo box: " & [Forms]![Input MOC]![cboMOC#].Value

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSelect)
qdf.Parameters(0).Value = [Forms]![Input MOC]![cboMOC#].Value
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
Do While Not rs.EOF
    Debug.Print rs!Email
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

If the recordset opens and prints the correct data in the Immediate window, revise your original code to handle the recordset in the same way.  If this code fails, show us the values for *strSelect* and the combo box, the full error message, and which line of this code triggers that error.

Comment: Perfect. It showed the data in the debugging window, and I incorporated it into my code, so it is now working!

Answer (score 1):

Multiple variables for same types of outlook objects then using variables inconsistently. Don't use CurrentDb as a declared variable - it is already an intrinsic constant. Don't need the ToRecipient variable.

This code works for me.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim OlApp As Object
Dim OlMail As Object

Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OlMail = OlApp.CreateItem(0)
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Email FROM [EmailList]")

With OlMail    
    Do While rs.EOF = False
        .Recipients.Add rs!Email
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    .Subject = "MOC"
    .HTMLbody = "<a href=""X:\MOC Training.accdb"">Click Here for Training</a><br>"
    .Display
End With
Set OlMail = Nothing
Set OlApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Minor comment: if you're using late binding (`Dim OlApp As Object`), `olmailitem` should be `0` else this enum won't be defined.

Comment: The enum `olmailitem` is only defined when using early binding with a reference to the MS Outlook Object Library.

Comment: I do have reference to MS Outlook library so the late binding is working but you are correct, need to use 0 if no library reference. User will get a compile error otherwise. Corrected answer.

Comment: When I run this code, I get the same error I use to. Run time error '3061'. Too few parameters. Expected 1. This is in reference to the 'Set rs' statement. I've attached the SQL code. It doesn't seem to be selecting the Email field from the query.                SELECT Employees.Email
FROM Employees LEFT JOIN Names2 ON Employees.Employee = Names2.[Names Trainee]
WHERE (((Names2.MOC)=[Forms]![Input MOC]![cboMOC#]));